# Term Bubbles in Search Engine

Tags: html, css, graphics

So I'll do my best to describe what I'm trying to do, but I think a picture will do more justice.

[image]

Basically I'm working on a search engine of sorts and the engine accepts comma-delimited keywords. The way I'd like it to work is after the user enters a term and puts a comma, the term appears below the search bar in a "bubble" that is sized appropriately, with an "x" that allows them to remove the term from their search.

Programmatically, I know how to do it. I'm a little stuck on how to do the graphics though. I know this is a programming forum, but I'm not sure if I should create the "base" graphic for the bubble and then have it dynamically size based on the length of the search term, or if there's some other way to do it.

Thoughts?

**EDIT: Wow, just remembered that StackExchange accomplishes exactly what I'm wanting, sans the 'x' option. That's what I want, except with more rounded styling.**

Comment: Depends on how fancy you want the buttons to be. You could accomplish something similar to your picture with pure css and it would stretch to fit whatever is inside of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    background: blue;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

… should do the trick. No need to play with graphics except for the delete icons.

Comment: How browser-compatible is this? I'm fairly new to web programming...I'm primarily in software dev.

Comment: [Pretty compatible](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius), and it is a cosmetic effect that degrades cleanly so that [shouldn't be a problem](http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/)

Comment: @Quentin: as long as you don't have to support the &^%$ browser of (older) IE :-)

Comment: It has the added benefit of requiring very little dev time and very little bandwidth (unlike anything that will involve images).

Comment: Good point. Check my OP, I edited it a little bit, and feel kind of stupid. Hah!

Answer (score 0):

Use the sliding doors technique...

http://kailoon.com/css-sliding-door-using-only-1-image/

and then have an auto width with padding either side.

Comment: This looks promising. I'll check this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can go either the HTML 5 way be adding rounded corners to `li`'s / `div`'s.

Look at the `border-radius` property for this. Although is isn't support by all (older / IE :) ) browsers.

Or

You can make something like the follwing (semi pseudocode):

```
<div class="button">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="content">Term</div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>

.button .left { background: url('image with the left part of the button'); width: the width of the image; }
.button .right { background: url('image with the rightpart of the button'); width: the width of the image; }
.button .content { background: gray; }
```

Which will have two sides (left / right) with the rounded corners as image and fixed width. And the middle content part which doesn't have a fixed width.

**EDIT**

Demo of the second way to go: http://jsfiddle.net/kc5ZC/4/

I just set the left / right with the same red background color. You would have to create left / right images with round corners for it.

Comment: That was my initial thought, but I thought it might get bulky. I'll have to check out HTML5...I don't know much about all its tricks and the fancy ones in CSS.

Comment: @Jon: Also updated my answer with a demo of the second situation.

Comment: Just checked it out. Looks like it works well. I'll explore this method.